# Как находя интервал между датами учитывать время только в пределах одного дня?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, процедуры

Необходимо проверить интервал между занятиями у одного тренера. Если перерыв между занятиями < 15 минут или > 3х часов, вывести информацию об этом. Kак я пытался это реализовать:

```sql
select
    count(*) into v_cnt3
from lesson l1,
     lesson l2
where l1.lesson_id <> l2.lesson_id
and   l1.lesson_coach_id = l2.lesson_coach_id
and   ((l1.lesson_start_date - l2.lesson_end_date)*24 > 3
or     (l1.lesson_start_date - l2.lesson_end_date)*24*60 < 15)
group by trunc(l1.lesson_start_date);

if v_cnt3 > 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('У одного или более тренеров интервал между занятиями меньше 15 минут или больше 3 часов');
end if;
```

Тестовые данные:

```sql
with lesson (lesson_id,lesson_section_id,lesson_coach_id,lesson_room,lesson_start_date,lesson_end_date) as (
    select 1,1,1,111,to_date ('16.04.2020 12:30','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),to_date ('16.04.2020 13:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 2,1,1,333,to_date ('16.04.2020 13:35','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),to_date ('16.04.2020 14:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 3,1,1,111,to_date ('16.04.2020 16:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),to_date ('16.04.2020 16:30','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 4,1,1,111,to_date ('16.04.2020 17:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),to_date ('16.04.2020 18:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
    select 5,1,1,111,to_date ('16.04.2020 19:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),to_date ('16.04.2020 20:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
)
select * from lesson
```

Появились проблемы:

1. Если у этого тренера есть записи о занятиях, которые проходят в разные дни, то данный запрос считает, что интервал между занятиями составляет более трех часов. Пытался пофиксить это с помощью `GROUP BY` по дате, но не получилось.
2. Если все записи в пределах одного дня, то часть запроса, проверяющая на интервал более трех часов прекрасно работает. Но с минутами сложнее - вычисляя, сколько минут прошло путем умножения числа часов в интервале на 60, этот запрос работает так, словно между занятиями прошло менее 15 минут, хотя это не так.

Comment: А где вы взяли тестовые данные? Всюду lesson_id=1, как их можно вставить, если там PK?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я забыл, что у меня триггер на автоинкремент.

Comment: Хорошо, бывает. На будующее, постарайтесь приводить данные, чтобы их можно было легче воспроизводить (см. правку с заменой вставок на CTE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пропущено условие соединение - "один и тот же день". Учитывать надо только занятия - каждое текущее и строго следующее за ним, для этого так же не хватает условия.

Итого:

```sql
select l1.*    
from lesson l1
join ( 
    select l.*, 
        lag (lesson_id) over (partition by lesson_coach_id order by lesson_start_date) prev
    from lesson l
) l2 on (
        l2.lesson_coach_id = l1.lesson_coach_id
    and l2.lesson_id <> l1.lesson_id
    and trunc (l2.lesson_start_date) = trunc (l1.lesson_start_date)
    and l2.prev = l1.lesson_id) 
where ((l2.lesson_start_date - l1.lesson_end_date)*24 > 3 or
       (l2.lesson_start_date - l1.lesson_end_date)*24*60 < 15)
/
```

Условия могут быть сложнее, если тренеры работают по ночам.

---

Как работает арифметика дат, смотрите так:

```sql
select 
    case when trunc (t1) = trunc (t2) then 'same day' else 'other day' end compare,
    (t2 - t1)*24*60 mins
from (select sysdate-1/24 t1, sysdate t2 from dual);

COMPARE         MINS
--------- ----------
same day          60
```

Comment: Спасибо, это условие учитывает дни. Но появилась еще проблема - оказывается, если у меня более 3х занятий в один день, и ни одна из этих записей не имеет интервал от предыдущей более чем в три часа (то есть ни одна запись не нарушает условие, и не должна учитываться) результатом все равно становится якобы то, что промежуток в три часа есть.

Comment: Дополнил, проверьте.

Comment: Не помогает. Я понял в чем дело, мне нужно отнимать от lesson_start_date значение ПРЕДЫДУЩЕЙ строки в поле lesson_end_date. А мой запрос (выяснил путем вывода значений переменных на экран, отнимает от текущей  lesson_start_date, lesson_end_date следующей строки. Тем самым, когда курсор доходит до последней строки, он отнимает от lesson_start_date последней строки, lesson_end_date самой первой (получается - следующей после последней) строки. И там выходит значение > 3 часов. Сижу, думаю как это пофиксить

Comment: Кстати, Ваше условие должно было это пофиксить, но что-то не выходит...

Comment: Потому, что оно учитывает не последующее, а **все** последующие.  Вам надо пронумеровать занятия за день оконной функцией `row_number()`. Тогда последнее условие - текущий-последующий - будет `l2.rn = l1.rn+1`. Добавте тестовые данные в вопрос (5-6 строк).

Comment: Не допонял про row_number(). Скинул скриншот тестовых данных, на которых он пишет, что интервал между занятиями более трех часов. Но это не так.

Comment: Тестовые данные всегда надо приводить текстом, не картинкой. 

В подзапросе: `row_number () over (partition by lesson_coach_id, trunc (lesson_start_date)  order by lesson_start_date) rn`

Проверить не могу, у меня данных нет.

Comment: Добавил текстом. Если я, конечно, Вас правильно понял. @0xdb

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли. А код в предыдущем коментарии совсем не помог?

Comment: Добавил его в запрос после select count(*) *тут добавил Ваш код*. Ошибка - ORA-00904: "L1"."RN": недопустимый идентификатор

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочли:  **В подзапросе**, результат будет виден только во внешнем запросе.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я не понимаю, где именно должен быть подзапрос? и как он должен выглядеть. @0xdb Поставил после count(*) select и ваш код, ошибка - ключевое слово FROM не найдено там, где ожидалось. И скобки уже везде ставил...

Comment: Переработал запрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Он работает. Осталось пара деталей, справлюсь уж сам. Вы очень помогли! @0xdb

Comment: Рад был помочь! Вот это `l1.lesson_start_date - l2.lesson_end_date`, как вы поняли, тоже было неверно - нельзя из прошлого отнимать будующее, надо всегда наоборот. Добавил в конце простейший пример, потренеруйтесь на будующее с арифметикой дат.